# What's the name of this kind of valve?

Tags: heating, thermostat, valve

I would like to install the smart radiator thermostat from my previous apartment:

[image: Smart thermostat with thread]

However, in the new apartment there are different kind of valves, with clamps, as seen here:

[image]

Does anyone know what's the name of this type of valve? Most likely I can buy converters, provided I know what to look for.

**UPDATE**

Took off the thermostat, and it is not threaded, so I need an adapter indeed.

[image]

Comment: Is it by chance just a cover?

Comment: Does the round top house a smalk electric motor attached to a stem that is attached to the valve disc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - when unmounting the thermostat, I noticed the manufacturer's name (Danfoss), and from that I was able to find the valve type, which is **Danfoss RAVL**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the existing valve, you loosen or remove the screw. This will allow the fingers under the grey strap to expand, allowing you to just pull the thermostat off.

To install your thermostat, move the metal ring down. It might actually be threaded, so turning it may be required. Push it on to the radiator, and move/turn the metal ring back in to place.

Comment: Thanks for the step-by-step tutorial, but it is not threaded, so I still need an adapter of some kind.